# Prevent duplicates being added to database table via PHP form

Tags: php, sql, linux, database

I want to log what a user enters into a PHP form, and make sure they are not entering data that already exists in a database table.

I have the code already that enters the data into the table from user input, but I'm not sure how to check for duplicates. For example I want to check that there is no product under the same name being added again.

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO user_date 
    SELECT 
        product_name = '$_POST[product_name]'
        ,code = '$_POST[code]'
        ,comments = '$_POST[comments]'
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE product_name = '$_POST[product_name]') ";
```

But I get an error:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'fdgfdg' code = 'fdgdfg' WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT *' at line 4
```

I'm aware of the security issues. Its not a live system but just to learn from it.

Comment: Select from the database first and see if there are any rows that match. If there are not then insert.

Comment: thats a simple syntax error...'= 'fdgfdg' must be= 'fdgfdg'

Comment: There is something terribly wrong with this part `= 'fdgfdg' password = 'fdgdfg' WHERE`. Is some script altering the query before it gets executed?

Comment: `I'm aware of the security issues.` So go fix them, it doesn't matter if it isn't production code ffs.

Comment: wait, doesn't sql use `and` instead of `,`?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have duplicate insert then use IGNORE at end of insert statement

```
 $sql = "
    INSERT INTO user_date 
    values
        ('$_POST[product_name]'
        ,'$_POST[code]'
        ,'$_POST[comments]')
   ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE";
```

So this way might help you

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE product_name = '$_POST[product_name]'");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($num_rows > 0) {
      // do something
    }
    else {
      // do something else
    }
```